# How to share data with a TreeView such as done by gtk_list_store

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qtreewidgetitem

I do managing an app with a TreeView in Qt/C++

In order to not mix File system access and window/UI management, I do have a create a C++ code which manage to interact with the FileSystem and a C++ class which is in charge of displaying the Tree

I have seen that Gtk had a

```
gtk_list_store_set(..)
```

is there any equivalent in C++ / Qt ?

What I would do is to be able to file the TreeWidgetItem using an API or method from the filesystem side and the display tree part just have to read this value.

Any idea on how to do it properly ?

I was thinking instantiate the class of TreeWidget inside the code of the FileSystem but I would like to make it smarter.

FileSystem file a treeview model and the ui read this model.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you are interested in on-demand population of children you should look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-fetchmore.html.

Answer (score 0):

If  I understood you correctly, there is a ready made solution in Qt for your problem. `QFileSystemModel` you can use it to access the file system, and than pass it to Widget.

If you are using MTP stack, you may need to implement your own model by subclassing QAbstrackItemModel http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html

Comment: The only thing is that the FS I access is through a MTP stack. I think that the FileSystemModel is mode linked to the FS of the local machine